# Как взаимодействовать со вторым окном в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, окно

у меня есть окно в tkinter,в нем есть кнопка,мне нужно,что бы при нажатии на нее,открывалось второе окно с текстом "Helo world"

```
from tkinter import*

def second_window():
    window = Toplevel()
    window.title("second window")
    window.geometry("400x300")
    label1 = Label(text="Helo world")
    label1.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("Window")
root.geometry("400x300")

btn = Button(text="create second window",activebackground="#555",command=lambda:second_window())
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

но при нажатии,открывается второе пустое окно,а "Helo world" выводится в первом окне,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Вам для вашего Label нужно установить родителя, так как по умолчанию родителем является главное окно.*

```
label1 = Label(window, text="Helo world")
```

Comment: Не заслуженно мне достались лавры, так как господин Alexshev92 ответил раньше.)

Comment: Ваш ответ был полнее, так что придётся смириться с лаврами )

Answer (score 4):

При создании лейбла необходимо указать окно, на котором он будет размещён:

```
label1 = Label(window, text="Helo world")
```